# How to change JSON POST request to handle HTTPS

Tags: json, swift, ssl

Below is my login function. It's a JSON POST request and before, when the URL was http, it worked flawlessly. I attached a JSON filled with the username/password of the user. Today we added a SSL Certificate and after switching the URL to https, it produced this error:

```
NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)
```

I'm not really sure what's going on. I typed that error into google and didn't get any where. I appreciate any help, thank you!

```
func login(params : Dictionary<String, String>, url : String, postCompleted : (succeeded: Bool, msg: String) -> ()) {
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var err: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if response != nil {
            if response.isKindOfClass(NSHTTPURLResponse) {
                httpResponse = response as NSHTTPURLResponse
                if let authorizationID = httpResponse.allHeaderFields["Authorization"] as String! {
                    Locksmith.saveData(["id":authorizationID], forUserAccount: currentUser, inService: "setUpAuthorizationId")
                }
                else {
                    println("Failed")
                }

            }
        }
        var err: NSError?
        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

        // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
        if(err != nil) {
            println(err!.localizedDescription)
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr!)'")
            postCompleted(succeeded: false, msg: "Error")
        }
        else {
            // The JSONObjectWithData constructor didn't return an error. But, we should still
            // check and make sure that json has a value using optional binding.
            if let parseJSON = json {
                // Okay, the parsedJSON is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it
                if let status = parseJSON["status"] as? String {
                    if let extractData = parseJSON["data"] as? NSDictionary {
                        let extractUserId:Int = extractData["id"] as Int
                        userId = extractUserId
                    }
                    if status == "success" {
                        postCompleted(succeeded: true, msg: "Logged in.")
                    } else {
                        let failMessage = parseJSON["message"] as? String
                        postCompleted(succeeded: false, msg: failMessage!)
                    }
                }
                return
            }
            else {
                // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                println("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
                postCompleted(succeeded: false, msg: "Error")
            }
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [This awesome article](https://medium.com/swift-programming/learn-nsurlsession-using-swift-ebd80205f87c) I was able to fix my problem. All I needed to do was add:

```
NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate
```

after my class name, and then add these two delegates:

```
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession,
    didReceiveChallenge challenge:
    NSURLAuthenticationChallenge,
    completionHandler:
    (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition,
    NSURLCredential!) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(
            NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential,
            NSURLCredential(forTrust:
                challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust))
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: NSHTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: (NSURLRequest!) -> Void) {
    var newRequest : NSURLRequest? = request
    println(newRequest?.description);
    completionHandler(newRequest)
}
```

after that in my actual request I just needed to change:

```
var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
```

to:

```
        var configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        var session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
```

hope this helps someone!!